# c++ program gets 2x slower when there is a dummy (noop) thread! possibly related to std::getline

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, getline

In a simple program that just counts num lines read from stdin, when a transient dummy thread is introduced, things get 2x slower.

Originally tried with c++11 threads, then reproduced with plain pthread. Happens with both gcc 4.9.2 and gcc 4.8.4. Happens on both AMD and Intel CPUs.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void* f(void* x) { return x; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Via a cmd flag, control whether or not to create the dummy thread:
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::cout << "Creating transient thread ..." << std::endl;
        pthread_t th;
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, f, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if (pthread_join(th, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        std::cout << "Transient thread going away" << std::endl;
    }

    // Read lines off of stdin and count:
    std::cout << "Counting lines ... ";
    std::string line;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; std::getline(std::cin, line) > 0; ++i) {
    }
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Run 1:

```
$ g++ test.cc -O2 -lpthread && time cat raw.txt | ./a.out
Counting lines ... 5000000
real    0m10.132s
user    0m9.843s
sys     0m0.518s
```

Run 2:

```
$ g++ test.cc -O2 -lpthread && time cat raw.txt | ./a.out 1
Creating transient thread ...
Transient thread going away
Counting lines ... 5000000
real    0m23.323s
user    0m22.483s
sys     0m1.437s
```

Comment: You're comparing the overall time, why are you surprised that launching a thread and joining it would incur overhead? You should use internal time reads to compare just the shared part of the code.

Comment: (side note) `getline(...)>0` is a strange test (invalid in C++11 for good reasons).

Comment: There could be heuristics (in libc, the kernel, etc) that make locking faster for single-threaded programs, where the test for single-threaded would be something very simple that does not include programs having temporarily only one thread.

Comment: The fine-grained locking necessary to make locale thread-safe is the probable reason.  Very big issue with iostream, it is completely ignorant of threading.  From the numbers, it looks like it is done for every single byte.  Ouch.  Lots of technical debt in the spec, threading was ignored entirely too long to still fix it.

Comment: @Leeor the actual code (from which I extracted this minimal) did an internal time measurement and verified this result. Also, even in this minimal example the run time is 10-20 sec and I can see the "Transient thread going away ..." well under 1 sec so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @HansPassant It's likely. the problem goes away when replacing std::getline with fgets()